# Cannot enter text into Java text boxes

Tags: java, macos, swing, java-web-start, dialog

I'm unable to enter text into text boxes in windows/dialog boxes produced by Java. For example, I can't type text into [Sun's "How to use text fields" example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/samples/uiswing/TextFieldDemoProject/TextFieldDemo.jnlp), (linked to from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)). However, I am able to click buttons in Java's windows.

I'm running on a Mac with the latest version of OS X (Yosemite 10.10.2), and the Java System Preferences pane assures me that I'm using the "recommended" version of Java (Java 8 Update 40). I should add that I'm running stuff via Java Web Start here, which generates some security warnings.

I told Java to enable the Java Console but it seems only to be showing start-up boiler-plate.

EDIT: to be clear, I'm able to reproduce this issue even in code from the makers of Java, so I don't think the fix will be something as simple as add a line or two to my code.

Comment: Works okay for me, 10.10.2/8.40

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of textbox you can add text;
Let the name of your textbox is mytextbox

```
mytextbox.setText("The text what you want to write");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like a way to make user-editable text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to set the 
`textBox.setEditable(true)`

Comment: No luck :(. But not surprising  given that the example code from the docs has the same issue.